# Using Fly Dynamic Image Resizer for ACF gallery

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Trying to use a great plugin "Fly Dynamic Image Resizer" to return images from ACF but not having much luck. Can anyone provide any clue as to what I may be doing wrong? Thanks.

ACF variables:

```
<?php
$photo = get_field('photo', $post); 
$fly_image = fly_get_attachment_image_src($photo, 'big_featured_works', true);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<img src="<?php echo $fly_image['src']; ?>"/>
```

Comment: Update: replaced photo variable like so: `$photo = $image['id'];` but of course it's not pulling the right images...

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're having more explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

```
$fly_image = fly_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('photo', $post), 'big_featured_works', true);

<img src="<?php echo $fly_image['src']; ?>"/>
```

then switch the return value of the custom field to image ID (from default "Image Array")

Answer (score 0):

If your field is a repeater field you'll have to use get_sub_field, like this:

```
$image = get_sub_field('image');

fly_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'image-custom-size')['src'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = fly_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'home_page_square', array( 500, 500 ), true );
echo '<img src="' . $image['src'] . '" width="' . $image['width'] . '" height="' . $image['height'] . '" />';
```

([Reference](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/fly-dynamic-image-resizer/))